# Ajax posting NAN value

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I'm posting a variable via ajax however when I use it in PHP, I get NAN why is that? it's supposed to be a number

//in js

```
var variableToSend = 1;
$.post('ajax.php', {variable: variableToSend});
```

//in php

```
<?php echo $_POST['variable']?>;
```

Comment: **where** are you getting "NaN"?

Comment: in my php file where i am calling the  <? php $_POST['varaible'];?>

Comment: NaN doesn't exist in PHP

Comment: Can you show us your full code ?

Comment: This code won't have the effect you describe (and even if it did, it isn't clear how you could tell since you aren't obviously inspecting the HTTP response). You need to provide a [mcve].

Comment: semicolon outside servlet? `?>;`

Comment: your javascript must be more than those two lines for `variableToSend` to end up being `NaN` ... the browser is sending `NaN`

Comment: There apparently is no way this shouldn't work. Either provide a verifiable example, either add informations like `var_dump($_POST);` and the http request sent by the client (you can log it using the browser tools, usually the "network" tab holds all the answers you need).

Answer (score 0):

This code won't work,

Because  AJAX is something that works in the background, So there is no way the "echo " in PHP will display the data, Because the data returns back to the `success:function`  and then that can be consoled or printed on the HTML

Here is an example code of how it works:

```
var variableToSend = 1;
$.ajax({
  url:"ajax.php",
  method:"POST",
  data: {
    variable:variableToSend
  },
  success:function(data){
    console.log(data);
  }
})
```

Hope you understood how AJAX works

Comment: so If i want to use a javascript variable in my php page how do I DO so

Comment: how do i access a javascript variable in PHP?

Comment: You have to remember that if JS and PHP live in the same document, the PHP will be executed first (at the server) and the JS will be executed second (at the browser)--and the two will NEVER interact (excepting where you output JS with PHP, which is not really an interaction between the two engines).

Comment: the closest you could come is to use is a  PHP variable in your JS:

Comment: Like this : var a = '<?php echo $a; ?>';

Comment: And then use this in php : <?php
$a = 'foo'; // $a now holds PHP string foo
?>

Comment: ou can't have a variable that both javascript and PHP both "know" about, they are running on completely separate machines

Comment: Hope you understood